# Specify Non-Standard Source Folder

Tags: build, rust, rust-cargo

I am writing a multi-language project (a Java library which loads and calls Rust functions through the FFI), and so I want to divide my code files up a little bit. Rather than just putting everything in `src`, I've made folders `src/rust` and `src/java`. How can I tell Cargo that my `lib.rs` file (and all of my other source files) is in `src/rust` rather than `src`? Additionally, how can I tell it to output to `out/rust` rather than `target`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To manually set the path to your `lib.rs` you can create a `[lib]` section in your `Cargo.toml` and set `path` to `src/rust/lib.rs`. The relevant Documentation can be found here: http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#configuring-a-target

For the output, you can set the environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` to `out`. Relevant documentation can be found here: http://doc.crates.io/config.html#environment-variables

Or you can create a `.cargo/config` file (also a `toml`-file, but no file extension) and add a `[build]` section with the key `target-dir` set to `out`. Relevant documentation can be found here: http://doc.crates.io/config.html#configuration-keys

Comment: is there an equivalent to `CARGO_TARGET_DIR`, except for the src directory? i'd rather not explicitly give the path to all the files.

Comment: you only need to specify the `lib.rs`, all the sub-modules don't need to be specified. In case you mean `[bin]`, `[test]` and `[bench]` targets, then yes, you need to specify one for each of them.